# How to create an excel file and update it by adding a new row of output data every new run?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, fwrite, xlsxwriter

I've created a .txt file that can save the new data every time I run the code. I hope there's a way to do this with .xls file to add the new data every time I run the file because it will help with other output data to write and read it later in other codes.

Here is the code I use for .txt file and the output.

```
with open('OUTPUT.txt', 'a+') as fd:
if fd.tell() == 0:
    fd.write('{a:^8}  {b:^8}    {c:^8}      {d:^8}  {e:^8}  {f:^8}'.format(a='M', b='D', c='pr',d='rpr',e='TRT',f='center '))
fd.write("\r")
fd.write(f'    {M}     {D}        {(pr(M,1))}                   {(epr(M))}           {TRT(bd)}       {center}')
fd.write("\r\n")
```

The output

```
     M        D          pr                     rpr            TRT         center
    5.5     18.0        0.009                   0.997           0       (42.98, 74.21)


    7.1     29.0        0.0                    1.012            59       (42.96, 71.71)


    7.7     1.0        0.0                     1.013            15       (45.80, 73.48)
```

Comment: Please show what you have done yourself to solve the problem you present here - as opposed to the problem you solved long ago and don't have anymore.

Comment: Thanks!. I was trying to show an example of what I am looking for, avoiding a long explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas and openpyxl library for the purpose. A very good article is given here[MEDIUM link](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-python-pandas-with-excel-d5082102ca27)